# Passing optional arguments to a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to pass an undefined number of optional arguments to a function. The optional arguments are stored a priori in a dictionary.

As an example:

```
def f(a=0, b=0, c=0):
    return a

my_args = {'a':5, 'b':3}

print(f(my_args))
```

The expected output would be `5`, however it is `{'a':5, 'b':3}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unpack the `dict`:

```
print(f(**my_args))
```